# Silex does not find routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, silex, php-7

I have a Silex 2.0 application with PHP 7.0 and Apache 2.4 (on port 8080) with the following structure:

```
silex/
   | - vendor/
   | - web/
        | - index.php
   | - composer.json
   | - .htaccess
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7",
        "silex/silex": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
FallbackResource /silex/web/index.php
```

**web/index.php**

```
<?php

define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
chdir(APP_ROOT);

use Silex\Application;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

echo "---------------- I am here! -----------------";

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    echo 'inside get';
   return $app->json(['Hello World!']);
});

$app->run();
```

**And the problem is this:**

[image: Silex Error -]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try http:/what.ever.com/silex/web/ ? It should work... You should also check the RewriteBase parameter if you are going to access your web application from /silex/ folder in the URL (not sure, because never used Apache 2.4 so far though :-)

Comment: Hey man, thanks! I used the PHP build-in web server, like this: php -S localhost:8000 -t web/. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the PHP build-in web server and it worked, like this:

php -S localhost:8000 -t web/